# Scala - groupBy map values to list

Tags: scala

I have the following input data

```
((A, 1, 4), (A, 2, 5), (A, 3, 6))
```

I would like to produce the following result

```
(A, (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

through grouping input by keys

What would be the correct way to do so in Scala?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about the types you're expecting? What is `A 1 4`? Individual strings? A string and two integers?

Comment: They are lists (A, 1, 4)

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have a functioning example that you've been working on which doesn't return the desired result?

Comment: @BotianZhong are they `List[List[Any]]` you mean? Or a `List[(String, Int, Int)]` (list of tuples)?

Comment: What are the keys? Your example only has one key value if it's "A". Can there be more keys? A more complete example would help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ((A, 1, 4), (A, 2, 5), (A, 3, 6))

In the case that this represents a `List[(String, Int, Int)]` type then try the following.

```
val l = List(("A", 1, 4), ("A", 2, 5), ("A", 3, 6), ("B", 1, 4), ("B", 2, 5), ("B", 3, 6))

l groupBy {_._1} map {
    case (k, v) => (k, v map {
        case (k, v1, v2) => (v1, v2)
    } unzip)
}
```

This will result in a `Map[String,(List[Int], List[Int])]`, *i.e.*, a map with string keys mapped to tuples of two lists.

> Map(A -> (List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)), B -> (List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)))

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def takeHeads[A](lists:List[List[A]]): (List[A], List[List[A]]) =
  (lists.map(_.head), lists.map(_.tail))

def translate[A](lists:List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] =
  if (lists.flatten.isEmpty) Nil else {
    val t = takeHeads(lists)
    t._1 :: translate(t._2)
  }

yourValue.groupBy(_.head).mapValues(v => translate(v.map(_.tail)))
```

This produces a Map[Any,Any] when used on your value... but it should get you going in the right direction.